# Sheet duplicating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I want one excel work sheet to be sitting in a public folder of Dropbox, and I want this sheet to be an  identical version of a sheet in a differrent workbook.  Is there a way of making one sheet equal another sheet or do I need to do it cell by cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Move/Copy` to clone the sheet to another workbook as a one-off copy, to get the formatting,

Then put for example `=('C:\Files\[BookName.xlsx]SheetName'!A1)` in A1, and drag that cell to the bottom-right corner of the sheet to clone the formulae over the page.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new blank workbook. Then, on original workbook, select all data that you want to duplicate. Copy same.
- Select cell A1 in new workbook.
- On the ribbon, select the *Home* tab. On the left hand side, under *Paste*, you will see a down arrow. Click it and select *Paste link*. Done!